# Group by JsonDocument's property with unknown type using Entity Framework Core

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, group-by, entity-framework-core-3.1

I'm using Entity Framework Core 3.1.5

I’m trying to group entities by some property of `JsonDocument`, which I don’t know its type.
`AdditionalData` is the `JsonDocument` property of the entities.

I need to execute the commands on the database.

I managed to do it with two restrictions

1. I specified the property’s type (with GetInt32)
2. The commands were executed on the client and not on the DB.

```
    IEnumerable<MetricEntity> metricEntities = _tenantDbContext.Set<MetricEntity>();
    var ii2 = metricEntities.Where(metric => metric.Name == metricName).GroupBy(e =>
        e.AdditionalData!.RootElement.GetProperty(groupByProperty).GetInt32())
    .Select(entities => new
    {
        Count = entities.Count(), MetType = entities.Key, Ent = entities,
    }).ToList();
```

I also managed to do it without getting all the entities in the result
and with the restriction that the commands were executed on the client and not on the DB.

```
var i2 = _tenantDbContext.Set<MetricEntity>()
.Where(metric => metric.Name == metricName)
.GroupBy(e =>
    e.AdditionalData!.RootElement.GetProperty(groupByProperty).GetString())
.Select(entities => new
{
    Count = entities.Count(), MetType = entities.Key
}).ToList();
```

But when I’m adding the entities to the result as follow:

```
var i2 = _tenantDbContext.Set<MetricEntity>()
.GroupBy(e =>
    e.AdditionalData!.RootElement.GetProperty(groupByProperty).GetString())
.Select(entities => new
{
    Count = entities.Count(), MetType = entities.Key, ent = entities,
}).ToList();
```

I’m getting the following exception:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: Processing of the LINQ expression '(GroupByShaperExpression:
KeySelector: ((m.AdditionalData)#>>{(@__groupByProperty_1)}),
ElementSelector:(EntityShaperExpression:
    EntityType: MetricEntity
    ValueBufferExpression:
        (ProjectionBindingExpression: EmptyProjectionMember)
    IsNullable: False
)
)' by 'RelationalProjectionBindingExpressionVisitor' failed. This may indicate either a bug or a limitation in EF Core. See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101433 for more detailed information.
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.RelationalProjectionBindingExpressionVisitor.VisitExtension(Expression extensionExpression)
   at System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.Accept(ExpressionVisitor visitor)
   at System.Linq.Expressions.ExpressionVisitor.Visit(Expression node)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.RelationalProjectionBindingExpressionVisitor.Visit(Expression expression)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.RelationalProjectionBindingExpressionVisitor.VisitNew(NewExpression newExpression)
   at System.Linq.Expressions.NewExpression.Accept(ExpressionVisitor visitor)
   at System.Linq.Expressions.ExpressionVisitor.Visit(Expression node)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.RelationalProjectionBindingExpressionVisitor.Visit(Expression expression)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.RelationalProjectionBindingExpressionVisitor.Translate(SelectExpression selectExpression, Expression expression)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.RelationalQueryableMethodTranslatingExpressionVisitor.TranslateSelect(ShapedQueryExpression source, LambdaExpression selector)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.QueryableMethodTranslatingExpressionVisitor.VisitMethodCall(MethodCallExpression methodCallExpression)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.RelationalQueryableMethodTranslatingExpressionVisitor.VisitMethodCall(MethodCallExpression methodCallExpression)
   at System.Linq.Expressions.MethodCallExpression.Accept(ExpressionVisitor visitor)
   at System.Linq.Expressions.ExpressionVisitor.Visit(Expression node)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.QueryCompilationContext.CreateQueryExecutor[TResult](Expression query)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.Database.CompileQuery[TResult](Expression query, Boolean async)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryCompiler.CompileQueryCore[TResult](IDatabase database, Expression query, IModel model, Boolean async)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryCompiler.<>c__DisplayClass9_0`1.<Execute>b__0()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.CompiledQueryCache.GetOrAddQueryCore[TFunc](Object cacheKey, Func`1 compiler)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.CompiledQueryCache.GetOrAddQuery[TResult](Object cacheKey, Func`1 compiler)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryCompiler.Execute[TResult](Expression query)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.EntityQueryProvider.Execute[TResult](Expression expression)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.EntityQueryable`1.GetEnumerator()
   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
```

Answer (score 0):

Each `group by` query should contain one or more *keys* and other properties which have aggregating function only in the select statement (`Sum`, `Count` and etc). EF tryed to convert LINQ to SQL query and throws the exception due no internal checks.

There is a workaround:

Evaluate table data before `GroupBy`. The following code loads all `MetricEntities` and groups it in c# code:

```
var i2 = _tenantDbContext.MetricEntities
.AsEnumerable()
.GroupBy(e =>
    e.AdditionalData!.RootElement.GetProperty(groupByProperty).GetString())
.Select(entities => new
{
    Count = entities.Count(), MetType = entities.Key, ent = entities,
}).ToList();
```

Comment: I need to execute the command in the database and not in the client.

Comment: In the results you are going to get all entities, so it's not necessary where your query will be executed. Selecting all data from the table will be faster then grouping and selecting data by conditions.

Comment: It is matter because after the operations I wrote in the question, I'm planning to aggregate the data somehow, (also in the DB) so I wont get all the entities from the DB. I can't afford getting thousands of entries from the DB. It takes too much time.

Comment: I'm sorry, but you've already done it:
`
.Select(entities => new
{
    Count = entities.Count(), MetType = entities.Key, ent = entities,
})
`

Every returned record will contain `ent` which have all data from the table.

Comment: I've found a lot of open issues on official repo on github. It seems that `GroupBy` is not fully supported by EF Core 3.1: [issue1](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/19929), [issue2](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/19202)

Comment: All the queries that I wrote in the question, were executed in client and not in the database. I checked the SQL log.